# windows phone 7 xap packaging

Tags: windows-phone-7, xap

When I try to change the tile notification I got this message and then I deleted what I wrote but still have the same message ? Is there anyone take this error message before ? Thanks

Error   1   Xap packaging failed. The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "res://StartMenu!AppIconGeneric.png". The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: Ok I just changed the icon from the properties and it worked I still did not recognized what the problem is but its working :)

Answer (score 3):

I got exactly same error message and updating the icon / tile files to something that truly exists on the disk did not immediately help.

Closing and restarting Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when your project contains a resource that is not existant on your disk, eg. when it was deleted in windows explorer.